# Apache Forrest as a Code Documentation Solution

Tags: java, maven-2, documentation-generation, apache-forrest

Lately,  I have been looking into Apache Forrest as a code documentation solution.  From Apache's website,

> "Apache Forrest™ software is a
>   publishing framework that transforms
>   input from various sources into a
>   unified presentation in one or more
>   output formats. The modular and
>   extensible plug-in architecture of
>   Apache Forrest is based on Apache
>   Cocoon and the relevant industry
>   standards that separate presentation
>   from content. Forrest can generate
>   static documents, or be used as a
>   dynamic server, or be deployed by its
>   automated facility."

I was wondering if Apache Forrest could be used as a way to organize and post documentation of some java code which is complete with JavaDoc comments.  I know JavaDoc can do it itself, but I feel like Apache Forrest provides some additional customization.  I found instructions on the Apache website on how to include it in Maven, but it appears to be tailored towards Maven 1.x and I use Maven 2.  Is something like this possible? And if so, what is the best way to go about integrating it?

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [Documenting Projects with Apache Forrest](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/05/26/forrest.html?page=last), the author writes this about **Forrest Alternatives**:

> If you're familiar with Maven, you may
>   be wondering why anyone would bother
>   with Forrest. Maven does everything
>   Forrest does, and much more:
>   completely automating your build,
>   attaching JUnit and CVS reports and
>   all sorts of additional useful
>   information on top of the basic
>   documentation. It even provides
>   targets to auto-install your newly
>   generated web site onto a remote host.
>
> I have used Maven on a number of
>   projects, and it's an impressive
>   package. The learning curve is not
>   much worse than Forrest's for basic
>   use, and since you don't have to learn
>   Ant if you use Maven, it's arguably
>   even less for setting up a project
>   from scratch. Forrest as a whole is
>   less complex, though, and if you don't
>   need everything Maven provides, you
>   might want to start with Forrest and
>   migrate to Maven later if you need it.
>   Forrest is also better if you have an
>   existing large-build system based on
>   Ant: it lets you add in Maven-style
>   web site generation incrementally
>   instead of rewriting all your build
>   scripts to Maven-ize the project.
>
> In terms of pure-documentation
>   alternatives, another solid option
>   with a lot of open source community
>   support is DocBook. You could write
>   the manual for a 747 with DocBook:
>   it's the ultimate SGML (or XML; there
>   are two versions) dialect for
>   technical writing. The XML variant has
>   a nice set of stylesheets from Norman
>   Walsh that can generate HTML, PDF, RTF
>   (Microsoft Word) and other formats
>   from DocBook source. I think Forrest's
>   XML dialect covers 80 percent of the
>   cases, with a much smaller learning
>   curve, but for a large project that
>   also needs to produce print
>   documentation, DocBook merits
>   consideration. Note that if you want
>   to migrate from DocBook, Forrest
>   supports rendering a subset of
>   DocBook/XML as well, but it is not
>   well supported. Forrest does not aim
>   to become a full-fledged DocBook
>   renderer any time in the future,
>   either, according to one of the
>   developers, so I would not rely upon
>   it as a format for new documentation
>   in Forrest.

So, as you're already using Maven, I really wonder why you would look at Forrest. Check out [Maven Doxia](http://maven.apache.org/doxia/index.html) if you still have some doubts about Maven's potential.

And if you want to use DocBook and if Maven's native support through Doxia is too limited, there is the [Docbkx Maven Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Docbkx+Maven+Plugin) (preferred over the [Maven Docbook plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/docbook-maven-plugin/)).

Comment: Thanks, I will check out both Doxia and DocBook.

Comment: In case the DocBook content should directly be integrated in the Maven Project Site, have a look into http://docbook-utils.sourceforge.net/maven-tidy-plugin_1.0/docbook/article-quick-start-docbook.html (Beta version available). Feedback is welcome through the Open Discussion Forum https://sourceforge.net/projects/docbook-utils/forums/forum/1123044